# Setting up Vala mode on Emacs

Tags: emacs, vala

I'm trying to set up a mode for editing Vala in Emacs. I've only found [these instructions](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/Emacs), and it seems that (for the first case with packages) marmalade no longer carries `vala-mode`, and for the second, `csharp-mode` always fails to compile when I try to install it! What should I do?

Comment: Marmalade [has vala-mode](http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/vala-mode).   Did you forget `M-x package-refresh-contents`?  Also, if something fails to compile, you'd better show the error message…

Comment: I *must* be doing something wrong. I have the following lines in my ``.emacs``:

``(add-to-list 'package-archives '("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/"))
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/"))
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("marmalade" . "http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/"))``

But when I try ``package-install``, I get no completions for ``vala-mode`` at all, even after ``M-x package-refresh-contents``.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just confirmed that `vala-mode` is not included in the marmalade archive, despite the link above. To work around this, from within `M-x eshell` execute:

```
$ wget http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/vala-mode-0.1.el
$ package-install-file vala-mode-0.1.el
```

`package-install` works with the network automatically, but `package-install-file`, and `package-install-from-buffer` are also available.

Of course this solution will not download it automatically going forward, so you should contact Marmalade maintainers to determine why it's not listing it in the archive, or possibly submit it for inclusion in Melpa.

Answer (score 0):

Another useful thing you can do is install and configure an LSP language server. I've had some success with https://github.com/Prince781/vala-language-server.

You can then install `lsp-mode` (https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-mode) and `lsp-ui` (https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-ui) for Emacs.

And then create a `compile_commands.json` file for your Vala project. E.g.

```
[
  {
    "directory": "/home/user/projects/example",
    "command": "/usr/bin/valac /home/user/projects/example/main.vala",
    "file": "/home/user/projects/example/main.vala"
   }
]
```

I haven't found an automatic way of doing this. But it's possible you could use CMake. CMake is definitely capable of generating a `compile_commands.json`. You would just need to describe your Vala project in a `CMakeLists.txt` file.

Then you add `(lsp)` to your `vala-mode-hook`:

```
(add-hook 'vala-mode-hook #'(lambda () (lsp)))
```